# Eager execution get trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow, eager-execution

In all the toturials (including tf official docs) that I see about tfe, The example uses the gradient tape, and manually adding all the gradients to the list of computed gradients e.g

```
variables = [w1, b1, w2, b2]  <--- manually store all the variables
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
 y_pred = model.predict(x, variables)
 loss = model.compute_loss(y_pred, y)
 grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables) < ---- send them to tape.gradient
 optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))
```

But is it the only way? even for huge models we need to accumulate all the parameters, or we somehow can access the defaults graph variables list
Trying to access `tf.get_default_graph().get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)`
or `trainable_variables` inside a tfe session gave the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding, Eager mode in TensorFlow stores information about model  in objects, for example in `tf.keras.Model` or `tf.estimator.Estimator`. In the absence of graph you can get the list of variables only there, using tf.keras.Model.trainable_variables for example. 
Eager mode, however, can work with graph object created explicitly. In this case, i think it will store list of variables. Without it, keras model object will be the only explicit storage for variables.

Comment: so just to make sure, if I use multiple `keras models` within my model, and I want to calculate the gradients, my only way is to store the variables myself? That's sound like a non-high level API way to go (thus I assume there is another way)

Comment: You can get them from keras.model. It's if you don't use keras you'll have to store them yourself. I think this is in active development and will be available in TF 2.0